# ErrorBinding Spring portlet MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

Disclaimer: I wished I had a through understanding before starting working with the framework.
But as it is of now, I'm lacking on that front, and hence the question.

I am working with Spring-Portlet MVC.

I have a flow, where in I take an input on a screen, validate the input, depending upon its result it either render same screen or next screen.

Implementation detail:

I have an action method which takes form backed command object. It checks whether entered input is valid or not. If it is not valid, it populate error message in BindingResult instance it takes as another argument.

We have different render method, to render different screen.

I'm taking command object as an argument in these render method. This command object I'm receiving is same as one passed to action.

Problem:

While rerendering a screen spring-mvc should bind the error message populated in action method. Currently when I take command object as argument in render method spring-mvc is somehow unable to bind that error message. But interesting enough it is able to bind the error message if I don't take command object as argument in render method and rather create a new command object altogether there.

can,some one having better understanding of spring-portlet mvc please explain this behaviour, or tell where I am lacking in understanding.

Regards,

Mawia

EDIT: Just to enrich the below answer: Though I didn't exactly isolated the issue which was causing the said behaviour, but the way I met my requirement was using modelattribute. ModelAttribute can be used either on method or a parameter to a method. It ensures that model will made available to all the call till the view is render(that is my understanding!). So we don't need to take command object as parameter in Render method, just annotate the commandObject parameter in action method with ModelAttribute and then you can get the same object returned from model as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the command/model object should be an argument/parameter in the render method. I have had the same issue trying to get the validation error messages when command/model is defined as argument in render method signature.  I typically have the command/object creation/populate in a separate method, like this:

```
@ModelAttribute(value="address")
public Address getAddress(@RequestParam Integer id){
    Address address = null;
    if(id != null){
        address = myService.getAddress(id);

    }else{
        address = new Address();
    }
    return address;
}
```

If I still need to access the ModelAttribute/command object from the render method, I typically get it by:

```
@RenderMapping
public String showAddressPage(ModelMap modelMap){
   Address address = modelMap.get("address");

   //make any additional changes to address

}
```

I used this example as reference [article](http://books.dzone.com/articles/spring-30-portlet-mvc-part-2)